# Where are coordinates stored in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export

I am brand new to ArcGIS Pro. I have never used this software before and know nothing about it.

I have a shapefile that I have imported to ArcGIS and I can't find the coordinates in the table. It has all these green dots that have been plotted all over the map.
I can click each dot and manually copy and paste the DMS coordinate data for each dot. But that's obviously a waste of time.

When I go into the table of the imported data, it has all types of information on each dot, but there is no field with the same coordinate data as shows up when I click the dot.

Where do I find this coordinate data?

I am simply looking to export to a readable file, a list of all the things that have been plotted on the map and what their coordinates are.

Comment: The coordinates are the basic information of the shapefile and usually not part of the attribute table, which holds additional information. You could export the shapefile as csv, then the coordinates should be attached as attributes.

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm

Comment: OK, Erik. How do I export the shapefile as CSV? I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.8.0

Comment: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012471

Comment: Erik, it doesn't work. It just exports the table with the regular fields, and no coordinates are attached. Do I need to check the box for "transfer geodatabase field properties" or "transfer field domain descriptions"?

Comment: You can also open the attribute table (R click the layer in Contents), add two new fields for your x and y coordinates, and then R click each field -> Calculate Geometry. You might also want to look up some basic tutorials for using ArcPro. They might answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: ycartwhelen, your solution worked. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add two new columns to the shapefile, then use field calculator or better yet the [Calculate Geometry](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm) tool to populate the values in the new fields. You could then Export the shapefile to csv or Excel. To Export to Excel, use the Table to Excel tool.

There are many ways to go about this, but this is a fairly simple workflow (Pro 2.7.0):
First Open Pro and Load your shapefile.

1. Open the **[Attribute Table](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/tables/open-tabular-data.htm)** for the shapefile(right click the layer in the table of contents, select Attribute table). It should open in a new pane, probably at the bottom of the pro window.
2. In the Attribute Table Pane. Click **Add** (top right of pane, next to Field: label)
3. This opens the [Fields pane](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/create-modify-and-delete-fields.htm) (should be stacked with the attribute table)
4. In the Fields Pane, fill out the required information for the new fields.

   - Add fields for x and y coordinates. If you would like the format of the coordinates to be DMS with formatting vs Decimal Degrees, be sure to make the field Type **Text**. If you want Decimal Degrees, Meters, or Feet, make sure to choose **Double**.
5. Once you have the fields created, make sure to click **Save** in the Fields Ribbon at the top of Pro.
6. Navigate back to the Attribute Table, yoiu should now see the two new fields appended to the end of the column
7. Be sure no features are selected (unless you only want to calculate selected features), you can do this by clicking **Clear** in the **Selection** section in the Attribute table pane.
8. Right click one of the new field headers to reveal a menu, midway down, select **Calculate Geometry**. This will open the **Calculate Geometry** Tool in a pop up window.
9. In the tool:

   - Make sure the shapefile is listed as the input
   - Select the two new fields as the target fields
   - Select the proper **Property** for each field

     - Latitude: Y coord
     - Longitude: X coord
   - Choose the **Coordinate Format**

     - If you don't know the input format, select the format you want to use.
     - Remember that the Field data type matters
   - Provide a Coordinate System if you want it to something other than the shapefiles. Otherwise this is optional and can be left blank.
10. Click Ok, the tool will run.
11. Verify the calculated data is correct in the attribute table.
12. Export to desired format.
13. To export to Excel, use the Export to Excel tool.

- To access tool, click analysis tab in the top ribbon in Pro, then click tools. From there you can search for "Excel". Choose **Table to Excel** and follow instructions.